# Firebase can't find referenced method

Tags: java, android, proguard

I get the following errors when building an APK with ProGuard:

[image]

ProGuard is using the default proguardfile and yet this issue has just appeared. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Please type in the error rather than posting the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Firebase authentication then, you need to add following lines in your proguard file:

```
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

The docs link for the above is: [Optional: Configure ProGuard](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start/#proguard)

In addition, as per documentation *if you use DataSnapshot.getValue(Class) or DatabaseReference.setValue(Object) to read and write data, you need to consider how your model objects will be serialized and deserialized after obfuscation* then, you need to add following:

```
# Add this global rule
-keepattributes Signature

# This rule will properly ProGuard all the model classes in
# the package com.yourcompany.models. Modify to fit the structure
# of your app.
  -keepclassmembers class com.yourcompany.models.** {
*;
}
```

Here is the link for the documentation: [Set up Firebase Realtime Database for Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/)